# Can run macro from clipboard but not from file?

Tags: automation, emeditor

I recently updated my EmEditor.

---

Previously:

- had macro stored locally
- could be run from inside app

After update:

- running macro from file within app produces "Expected statement" for a line which has been commented out in the script (preceded with "//")

However, I can run the script if I copy the script to the clipboard and run in the app by going:
Menu "Macro">>"Run clipboard".

---

**What could be causing this and how do I get the app to run the script without having to run it from clipboard?**

Comment: You probably need to do some investigation and testing in order to be able to provide more information. Remove the comment from the script. does it run then? Do some investigation why this issue occurs. Start with an easy "hello world" example script. Find out what exactly does the script make not run. Also [Without code, it is very hard to help you](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/). If the problem persists please share a [mcve] that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Please make sure you are using the latest version of EmEditor.

Comment: Thank you gents, both. Testing has been conducted on two machines with seemingly identical settings on the app; both running the most up to date pro version.
We changed the macro language from VBA to Java which seemed to remedy this for one of the machines and solved the problem for our processor. Therefore the behavior persists (on one machine) but the problem is resolved where needed. So, the problem is "fixed" although the cause is still a mystery. Thank you both again.

Comment: Please try clearing the `Run macros asynchronously by default` option in the `Customize Macros` dialog box (on the `Macros` menu - `Customize`). If you find a reproducible VB Script, please make it as simple as possible and share with us (or email me).